# Could logback has root level lower than other loggers?

Tags: java, logback

Can I have the level of root logger at ERROR and other loggers like "com.test.abc" at DEBUG? Why does this not work? I can do this in log4j.

```xml
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date{HH:mm:ss} %-5level [%thread] - [%logger{0}]- %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <logger name="com.test.abc" level="DEBUG" additivity="false"/>

    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Your snippet shows that you have your root logger configured on `DEBUG` level rather than `ERROR`?

Comment: That's my mistake. I fixed it.

Comment: It works for me

Comment: Could you post your code? I tried many ways. Which version of logback do you use?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you don't see any debug logging is because your logger tag is empty, those log statements will go "nowhere".  And since `additivity="false"` is won't be included in the root logger either.

You can try this:

```xml
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date{HH:mm:ss} %-5level [%thread] - [%logger{0}]- %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.test.abc" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </logger>

    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I need to remove this 

    additivity="false"